# C++ arrays and size

Tags: c++, arrays, size

If I have for example the following array declaration: `int a[5];`, this means that I have an array "a" that holds **5** integer variables.

Wouldn't it be in memory something like this (See the `\0`)?

---

### |0|1|2|3|4|\0|

So, in this case, do I still say that `a[]` is of size `5` or should I say it is of size `6`?

And, if I copy it to the array: int b[4] what will happen in this case? What will happen to the integer variable in location `4` of `a[]`, will it overwrite `\0`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Arrays are not, in general, automatically zero-terminated. C strings are zero-terminated, but this is not a C string.

Comment: @David Heffernan. Thanks for your reply. Just to confirm, "\0" means a new line, is that right?

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that when declaring a C string, space for the zero terminator has to be reserved explicitly. That is, `char s[11];` for a 10-byte string.

Comment: @aali, a new line is '\n' or maybe "\r\n" or '\r' depending on the platform. '\0' is just a zero byte (it doesn't represent any printable character).

Comment: @aali, \0 means end of sequence in memory. That's something completely different compared to \n.

Comment: @aali: No, '\0' is the null character, not a new line. (Also, "\0", is a C null terminated string that contains two null characters the explicitly typed one, and the implicitly added by the compiler at the end of the literal, which is different from '\0'). I recommend that you take a nice introductory book on C++ and work from there on.

Comment: @Sergey That's true, but normally C strings are declared as such: `char *s = "This is a zero-terminated string";`. At least, that's my understanding.

Comment: @David, yes, but not always. For example, you could be reading a string from some sort of input stream and it's important to allocate one byte more than the maximum length you plan on reading. That is, unless the reading function is smart enough to read a maximum of size-1 bytes.

Comment: @Sergey Good point. Is `char s[11] ` even a C string or is it actually just a character array? Does it become a C string when you refer to it as the address of the first character? I'm actually not a C/C++ guru at all!!

Comment: @David, to be precise, it is a character array that stores a C string. If it's zero terminated, it's a C string. If not, it's just a character array.

Answer (score 6):

There are only |0|1|2|3|4| in the memory, not the sixth one. So the size is 5.

Answer (score 2):

Great [explanation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) of arrays for beginners.